# How check a textbox for data when switching tabs with tabcontrols

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox, tabcontrol

I am looking for a way to check if data is entered in 2 textboxes when I switch tabs on a tabcontrol.

I am also wondering how I can use a button to specify what tab to go to on a click.

I tried using the tabcontrol1.click to setup the textbox check but it makes the warning go off when you click on any tab even just trying to go back to enter the data.

-thanks for the help!

```
    Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
    If fNameTxtBox.Text = "" Or
        IDTxtBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a Name and ID number.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        fNameTxtBox.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The TabControl has a `SelectedIndexChanged` event when the TabPage changes.  It also has a `Selecting` event (and `Selected`) which happens before the tab page changes and allows you to cancel teh change. Not sure why you need a button to click to change tabpages which also happen on a click

Comment: thanks Ill check those out. The button is needed because the teacher said we need a button... haha. I don't think it is normally needed.

Comment: Updated post with code - I think I need to be able to specify what tab I am selecting. It still is prompting for every tab change and still changes tabs even while throwing the messagebox.

Comment: look at the `e` argument you are passed- it contains **vital information** about the event like which tabindex is changed/changing/abut to change. you need to test which tab is involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
    If fNameTxtBox.Text = "" Or
     IDTxtBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a Name and ID number.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        e.Cancel = True '<<<< were telling VB that the event shoulb be terminated
        fNameTxtBox.Focus()
    End If

End Sub

'For Button
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If fNameTxtBox.Text = "" Or
      IDTxtBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a Name and ID number.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)

        'Choose one here
        TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1 'Assuming TabPage1 is the tab where the fNameTxtBox is resides
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 'Assuming the index number of the TabPage in the tab control where the fNameTxtBox is resides

        fNameTxtBox.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it's still going to fire every time a tabpage is clicked not just when he changes from the tabpage containing the textbox.

Comment: perfect! I thought that by default it would have been true from the first line.

I am still trying to figure out how to specify what tab to go to from a button click though.

Comment: by default the first page is loading and this makes it so they cannot leave the tab without entering the data so it works.

Comment: I've update the answer to include button, see my post.

Comment: That throws an error "an invalid cast exception was unhandled - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs'." .... tempted to remove the buttons and just take the minus a couple points. Been a little frustrating